# Can I buy another flight from another airline and travel to the same place before the registered flight?

Tags: passports, tickets, international-travel, fees-and-charges

I want to know if I can buy a flight before the scheduled flight. I have a reserved flight, I want to know if I can buy another flight to the same destination (italy) without any problem. I want to know if I'm charged for buying another flight.
The airline that I have reserved is '' AIR ITALY '' for August. I want to buy another flight from a different airline and travel to Italy before the scheduled day

Comment: I have read your text several times now and have absolutely no clue what you are trying to ask about. Can you please try to be more clear? Perhaps you can leave out everything not relevant to what you are trying to ask about and then be more detailed about the actual question?

Comment: Totally agree - just about to add a similar comment. Dates of booked and intended travel would probably help too

Comment: In short words, I want to know if I can buy a flight before the scheduled flight. I have a reserved flight, I want to know if I can buy another flight to the same destination (italy) without any problem. I want to know if I'm charged for buying another flight.

Comment: Could the question be "can I change my reservation to another date"? If that is the question, the answer is that it will depend. Mostly on the type of fare booked.

Comment: The question is quite clear upon reading it again.

Comment: You can of course buy as many flights as you want and you will have to pay for each of them. But I think that's not what you wanted to ask, is it? Please specify what tickets you already have, what ones would you like to add and what exactly are you concerned about.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn Is it? Then perhaps you could edit it a little to help the rest of us?

Comment: You can, as long as you do not want to use only the second half of a return ticket to get back home.

Comment: Is the question solely about the flights, or is it maybe about visas and changing plans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can buy multiple tickets to the same location on different day with travel dates prior to a previously purchased ticket.

For example you can purchase an American Airline (or other airline) ticket to London leaving on 10 March and returning on 17 March and immediately after that purchase the same itinerary on the same or even different airline leaving tomorrow February 26 and returning any day in the future.

The fact that you already have a ticket to the destination on a later date does not preclude you from buying another earlier ticket to the same destination.

I have previously done that for routes I frequently travel.

What you can’t do though, is use a return leg without taking the outbound flight.

Comment: What the OP can’t do though, is use a return leg without taking the outbound flight. I wondered if that was a thought behind the question. Although to be honest the question still puzzled me - why would anyone think you can’t buy multiple tickets, and why would they ask if they’d be charged? Still doesn’t make sense 100%

Comment: But what about if I stay during the first flight reservation? For Example, My Flight is in August until september. But I want to Buy another flight for a different airline  from June until September. What would happen? they will not charge me for anything and Just lose the first flight? Thats What also want to know. Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect not to be charged for a flight you purchased? Even if you choose not to use it?

Comment: @kevin Sandoval Assuming ‘they’ is your first airline, then no, you just lose your flight and the money you’ve paid. It might be cheaper to cancel and pay a cancellation fee, depending on the original ticket cost and airline cancellation policy. Are you asking if there’s a ‘no show’ fee as well? How would either airline know you had a ticket with the other one? You can’t fly out with one airline on a new ticket, and fly back with your original first ticket though.

Comment: @Traveller Okay, I understand what worried me is that I did not know if I would have problems at the airport to travel earlier than expected. My concern was that when I was in Italy and I returned to the United States in Italy, I would have problems to have different tickets purchased and be confused with the first flight (which I did not travel) with the new one I intend to buy. I do not know if I explain myself well, but thanks for your comments, Your help me a lot.

Comment: @kelvinsandoval If you have another question, yours allowed to ask that as a completely different question.

Comment: Yes, I had a Question, What you mean with ‘’No Shows’’ what exactly is that?

Comment: A no show is when you do not show up at the airport to take your flight. In that situation most airlines let you pay a penalty, then they reprice the ticket for the new date you want to travel on. If that turns out to be more expensive than a new ticket, you can abandon the old ticket altogether.

Comment: For example, my original ticket is one way. What happens if I buy another round trip ticket for not wanting to go on the scheduled date? Are they canceled while I'm at the airport? Thats my last question

Comment: @kelvin Sandoval Isn’t that virtually the same question you originally asked? If you buy and travel on another ticket, your original ticket just lapses - or possibly the airline will sell it to someone wanting to travel on that flight. It’s like a theatre ticket - you pay for your seat, if you don’t go to see the show either your seat is empty during the performance or someone else buys it and sits there. Either way you have paid for something you don’t use and you don’t get your money back unless you cancel within the cancellation terms.